# How to extract specific string in R and puts into another column?

Tags: r, regex

I have data like this, below are the 3 rows from my data set:

```
total=7871MB;free=5711MB;used=2159MB;shared=0MB;buffers=304MB;cached=1059MB;
free=71MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;cached=1059MB;
cached=1059MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;free=109MB;
```

Expected output as below,

```
total   free    used     shared  buffers  cached
7871MB  5711MB  2159MB   0MB     304MB    1059MB
5751MB  71MB    5MB      3159MB  30MB     1059MB
5751MB  109MB   5MB      3159MB  30MB     1059MB
```

and the problem here is I want to make different columns using above data like `total value`, `free value`, `used value`, `shared value`.

I can do that by splitting using `;` but in other rows values are getting shuffled, like first value coming as free then total followed by other values,

Is there any way using REGEX in , if we find total get value till `;` and put into one column, if we find free get value till `;` and put into another column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility using `strsplit`.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ";"), strsplit, "=")), nrow = 2))
colnames(df) = df[1,]
df = df[-1,]
df

#    total   free   used shared buffers cached
# 2 7871MB 5711MB 2159MB    0MB   304MB 1059MB
```

---

## Edit

I don't know how your data are structured. But you can do something like the following:

```
x <- "total=7871MB;free=5711MB;used=2159MB;shared=0MB; buffers=304MB;cached=1059MB;
free=71MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;cached=1059MB;
cached=1059MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;free=109MB;"

x %>% str_split("\n") %>% unlist() %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(total = str_extract(value, "total=(.*?)MB;"),
         free = str_extract(value, "free=(.*?)MB;"),
         used = str_extract(value, "used=(.*?)MB;"),
         shared = str_extract(value, "shared=(.*?)MB;"),
         buffers = str_extract(value, "buffers=(.*?)MB;"),
         cached = str_extract(value, "cached=(.*?)MB;")) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(str_extract(.,"[[:digit:]]+")))

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   total  free  used shared buffers cached
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 7871. 5711. 2159.     0.    304.  1059.
# 2 5751.   71.    5.  3159.     30.  1059.
# 3 5751.  109.    5.  3159.     30.  1059.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply, I understood we can split this string ,but the problem I am facing is values are not in same format ,like
perf_data
------------------------------------
1) total=7871MB;free=5711MB;used=2159MB;shared=0MB; buffers=304MB;cached=1059MB;
2)free=71MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;cached=1059MB;
3)cached=1059MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;free=109MB;

Comment: Thank you so much, Appreciate your effort .It worked as expected .Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `strsplit` followed by `sub` to separate the data from the labels.  Then, create a data frame using this data:

```
x <- 'total=7871MB;free=5711MB;used=2159MB;shared=0MB;buffers=304MB;cached=1059MB;'
y <- unlist(strsplit(x, ';'))
names <- sapply(y, function(x) gsub("=.*$", "", x))
data <- sapply(y, function(x) gsub(".*=", "", x, perl=TRUE))
df <- data.frame(names=names, data=data)
df
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply, I understood we can split this string ,but the problem I am facing is values are not in same format ,like
perf_data
------------------------------------
1) total=7871MB;free=5711MB;used=2159MB;shared=0MB; buffers=304MB;cached=1059MB;
2)free=71MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;cached=1059MB;
3)cached=1059MB;total=5751MB;shared=3159MB;used=5MB;buffers=30MB;free=109MB;

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem.  Edit your question and show sample data for which my script fails.